# Why doesn't constructor of prototype point Object function?

Tags: javascript

I'm new for javascript

I'm curious about prototype object.

All object has __proto__ and constructor property.
and all function has one more property named prototype.

As far as I know,
constructor means the pointer to a function that is used to initialize this object.

I'm curious about that why every prototype's constructor doesn't point Object function.
as you know that prototype is instance of Object function, so I thought prototype's constructor would direct Object function.
But It didn't, prototype's constructor direct the function which has that as prototype.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7rSY.png)

Comment: I'm certain I've seen similar questions, but I'm not sure what keywords to search for. "object" and "prototype" will find lots of unrelated questions.

Comment: [`__proto__` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto), use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) instead.

Comment: "*All Object has [[prototype]] and constructor property*" - no. Only `someFunction.prototype` objects do have `.constructor` property. That's wrong in your diagram: `Object` and `Function` do not have own `.constructor` properties. Instead, they inherit it from `Function.prototype`.

Comment: but you could check Function.constructor and Object.constructor in console.
Object.constructor point to Function because I assume Object is instance of Function. that's why I wander somefunction.prototype doesn't point to Object function although somefunction.prototype is instance of Object function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor always refer to an function not an Object, no matter it's proto or prototype.

here are some links to help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b

now as to why it is a function has to do with the fact when a object or function is initialized a constructor function is always executed, also this constructor function can be modified for the user by accepting parameters.

Honestly like barmer , i'm pretty sure the question is solved, try looking for them.

Comment: but I have a one more question to ask you. 
First, What I means for word "Object" is a "Object function". not Object like JSON.
Sorry to confuse you. 
My point was actually somefunction.prototype is instance of Object function. but somefunction.prototype.constructor point to somefunction, not Object function.
Why does that happen?

Comment: @JangchunLee The constructor of a class is a function with the same name as the class, it's called when you do `new classname`. So when you do `new Object`, it calls a function named `Object`.